# Cmdline to swap mouse buttons back

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, mouse

As a non-admin user without access to the reg command, how do I swap the mouse buttons back so that the primary button is the left button.

The command

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll,SwpmMouseButton
```

will set the primary button as the right button.  I tried calling it twice but it didn't switch back.  I've tried

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll,SwapMouseButton 0
rundll32.exe user32.dll,SwapMouseButton 1
```

but the primary button is still right right button.  From the cmdline, is it possible to swap the buttons back so that the left button is the primary button.

If there is no way of doing this from cmd, can it be done using powershell?

Comment: Do you not have  a mouse App to do this?

Comment: I can use main.cpl and alt S if it appears on the correct tab but sometimes main.cpl appears on the wrong tab

Comment: Perhaps ask the company to update the mouse driver (restart after) and see if that helps.

Comment: Maybe it is the way I am passing the 0 and 1 into SwapMouseButtons.  That call is supposed to take TRUE for right and FALSE for left.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-swapmousebutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it can't be done this way because rundll32.exe does not parse the 1 or 0.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806575/how-do-i-use-rundll32-to-swapmousebutton

An alternative is to use the powershell add-type command.  Say the script is called swap.ps1

```
# Define the parameter
param (
    [string]$side = "L"
)
# Create an external definition
$swapbuttons = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 SwapMouseButton(Int32 swap);
'@
# Add class
$swapper = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $swapbuttons -Name "swap" -Namespace "user" -PassThru
$setting = if ($side -eq "L") {0} else {1}
$result = $swapper::SwapMouseButton($setting)
```

To swap to the Left side

.\swap.ps1 L